# How to generate Map Tiles using OSM (Open Street Map) PBF files

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dictionary, openstreetmap, maptiler

I am developing a real estate web site and I need to have a map feature on it (obviously), this website won't be even close to exceeding the free threshold if I want to use google maps but I have decided I want to have my own map rendering feature for the sake of development fun.

I know using OpenStreetMap, you can download a PBF file for any region you want which contains all the data, and then you are apparentlt able to "generate your own tile" according to the OSM website.

I have no experience on that side, and I would like to get some general direction to start. To make it more clear, I am developing a single page app; my server side is being developed on ASP.Net Web Api 2 and client side is using angularjs, etc.

I would appreciate any general or details guideline on this, and where to start, etc.

Comment: check out http://switch2osm.org/

Comment: And maybe https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering